# The certificate is not trusted elasticsearch, but I do have the SSL certificates

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl

when trying to access endpoints of my self-hosted elasticsearch,

On Safari I get:
[image]

And on my client I get `code: -67843, message: "The certificate was not trusted.`

However when I request information from the `https://localhost:9200/_ssl/certificates` endpoint on postman (which accepts invalid certs) I get an array full of certs:

```
[
    {
        "path": "certs/http.p12",
        "format": "PKCS12",
        "alias": "http",
        "subject_dn": "CN=05eeab4fdxxx",
        "serial_number": "5126e9dc2658e8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "has_private_key": true,
        "expiry": "2024-06-26T19:29:39.000Z"
    },
    {
        "path": "certs/http.p12",
        "format": "PKCS12",
        "alias": "http",
        "subject_dn": "CN=Elasticsearch security auto-configuration HTTP CA",
        "serial_number": "ca270f5cdc32982970c192c6cxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "has_private_key": false,
        "expiry": "2025-06-26T19:29:39.000Z"
    },
    {
        "path": "certs/http.p12",
        "format": "PKCS12",
        "alias": "http_ca",
        "subject_dn": "CN=Elasticsearch security auto-configuration HTTP CA",
        "serial_number": "ca270f5cdc32982970c192c6c25xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "has_private_key": true,
        "expiry": "2025-06-26T19:29:39.000Z"
    },
    {
        "path": "certs/transport.p12",
        "format": "PKCS12",
        "alias": "transport",
        "subject_dn": "CN=Elasticsearch security auto-configuration HTTP CA",
        "serial_number": "19c5505398d30c56b0ea320exxxxxxxxxx",
        "has_private_key": false,
        "expiry": "2121-06-03T19:29:36.000Z"
    },
    {
        "path": "certs/transport.p12",
        "format": "PKCS12",
        "alias": "transport",
        "subject_dn": "CN=05eeab4fd435",
        "serial_number": "eb743df4612a20b23d3exxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "has_private_key": true,
        "expiry": "2121-06-03T19:29:38.000Z"
    },
    {
        "path": "certs/transport.p12",
        "format": "PKCS12",
        "alias": "transport_ca",
        "subject_dn": "CN=Elasticsearch security auto-configuration HTTP CA",
        "serial_number": "19c5505398d30c56b0eaxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "has_private_key": false,
        "expiry": "2121-06-03T19:29:36.000Z"
    }
]
```

Meaning I do have SSL certs up and running, I would guess. So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: The error doesn't means that you haven't certificates. It means that your certificate is not trusted. Self signed certificates are not trusted by browsers. Also it's impossible to create a trusted certificate for localhost

Comment: @EliasSoares ah, pain. Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

So you can actually pass in an object into the `transport` object through a method called `cert_validation()`... to fix my code, I did the following.

```
let cert: CertificateValidation = CertificateValidation::None;
let transport = TransportBuilder::new(conn_pool).auth(credentials).cert_validation(cert).build()?;
```

Unsafe and temporary.

Comment: If you have self-signed certificates, you can pass these to the client to use. See https://docs.rs/elasticsearch/8.4.0-alpha.1/elasticsearch/cert/enum.CertificateValidation.html#examples. Looking at the certs output, I think you'd want `CertificateValidation::Certificate(cert)`, where `cert` is a PEM or DER encoded cert: https://docs.rs/elasticsearch/8.4.0-alpha.1/elasticsearch/cert/struct.Certificate.html